# Fabric texture not showing in viewport

Tags: texturing

[image]

Hi, I downloaded this texture but it's not showing on viewport.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxRxn.jpg)

[image]

Comment: could you please pack the image and share the file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/syR1X06p

Comment: The node tries to find the image in //maps\\Chocofur_Fabric_Patterned_02_diff.jpg (from the blend file location). Do you have it?

Comment: thanks but there is no image in your file, first make sure that you can see the image in the UV Editor, then you need to go in File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend, then share again  ;)

Comment: Oh ok. I want to add it to a piece of clothing I’ve made in a separate file. How do I add this texture onto the clothing?

Comment: If you know where the jpg file is, just get it using the image texture node (using the folder button).

Comment: Ways to use PBR textures and load them up in Blender are explained in almost every tutorial about PBR. Text example https://www.cgbookcase.com/textures/how-to-use-pbr-textures-in-blender. Video tutorials are made in particular by BlenderGuru and CGCookie. When including textures in .blend file to share make sure their licence allows that